# spring cloud refresh config doesn't remove old key

Tags: config, spring-cloud

I wrote my property class like this

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "third")
```

and my application.yml is

```
third: 
  key1: 
    field1: value1
    field2: value2
  key2:
    field1: value1
    field2: value2
```

it will render `third.key1` and `third.key2`
But when I remove key2 in my application.yml

```
third: 
  key1: 
    field1: value1
    field2: value2
#  key2:
#    field1: value1
#    field2: value2
```

then post `actuator/refresh`, it response `third.key2`
The response shows it has recognized things changed in `application.yml`
the bean stil render `third.key1` and `third.key2`

Answer (score 1):

You can not delete a property by not providing it in a listing related to a "refresh" (aka update) process... If a property is not listed in such a list it is logical to assume it is simply do not need refresh - its value stays as it was before...

Instead of not providing it, provide it with an empty value.

```
third: 
  key1: 
    field1: value1
    field2: value2
  key2:
```

or in json:

```
{
  "third" : {
    "key1" : {
      "field1" : "value1"
      "field2" : "value2"
    },
    "key2" : ""
  }
}
```

This should delete it.

Comment: You are right, keeping the property empty, will propagate an update to the clients. But let's assume, you defined in your application a property (as default) and the same property in your remote repo. If you then clear the remote repo file, no update is being propagated and you won't be able to 'refresh' the value to be the default value, except by restarting the application... :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you want refresh the config dynamic , you should add an annotation in the class `@RefreshScope`.

```
@Component
@RefreshScope
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "third")
```

Also, your requirement need another component `springcloud bus`, you can check it in `spring.io`

Comment: thanks~  I also find something in this [doc](https://gist.github.com/dsyer/a43fe5f74427b371519af68c5c4904c7#configurationproperties).  `@ConfigurationProperties` bean is same with `@RefreshScope`. However the  [/refresh](https://gist.github.com/dsyer/a43fe5f74427b371519af68c5c4904c7#the-refresh-endpoint) endpoint just does not detect deleted keys, or changes in array lengths for some reason...